# width 100% который расширяется по содержимому

Tags: css, html

Всем привет, верстаю шаблон, в нём есть "корневой div"(id:indexRootOut) который должен растягиваться на всю ширину экрана, внутри есть два div'a id:indexTopRow1 и id:indexTopRow2, div id:indexTopRow1 содержит три элемента : лого, поиск и две кнопки(вход и рега). При слишком узком экране, все элементы сжимаются до минимальной ширины(у id:indexRootOut min-width: 800px), а при широком экране - растягиваются до максимальной(у id:indexTopInn max-width: 1280px). Всё работает нормально когда экран достаточно широкий, но когда ширина экрана меньше минимальной(800px) то получается вот это :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Flex'ами пробовал, результат аналогичный, div id:indexTopUserMenuOut должен изменять свою ширину в зависимости от ширины кнопок(т.к. на разных языках длина слов "вход" и "рега" будет отличаться)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<base href="/" />
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="theme-color" content="#c21616" />
<meta name="Description" content="">
<title></title>

</head>
<body>

<div id="indexRootOut">
<div id="indexRootInn">

<div id="indexTopOut" style="background-color: #c21616;">
<div id="indexTopInn">

<div id="indexTopRow1">
<div id="indexTopLogo"><a href=""></a></div><!--indexTopLogo/-->

<div id="indexTopFindOut">
<input id="indexTopFindHTMLInput" type="text" value="">
<div id="indexTopFindHTMLButt" class="HTMLButt indexTopButt">найти</div>
</div><!--indexTopFindOut/-->

<div id="indexTopUserMenuOut"><!--
--><div class="HTMLButt indexTopButt" style="border-radius: 25px 0px 0px 25px;">вход</div><!--
--><div class="HTMLButt indexTopButt" style="border-radius: 0px 25px 25px 0px; border-left-width: 0px;">регистрация</div>
</div><!--indexTopUserMenuOut/-->
</div><!--indexTopRow1/-->

<div style="height: 26px;"></div><!--delim-->

<div id="indexTopRow2">
<div id="indexTopMenuOut">

<div class="indexTopMenuElem indexTopMenuActElem"><a href="">Популярное</a><div>Популярное</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Все категории</a><div>Все категории</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Текст</a><div>Текст</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Текст</a><div>Текст</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Текст</a><div>Текст</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Текст</a><div>Текст</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Текст</a><div>Текст</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Текст</a><div>Текст</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Текст</a><div>Текст</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Текст</a><div>Текст</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

<div class="indexTopMenuElem"><a href="">Текст</a><div>Текст</div></div><!--/indexTopMenuElem-->

</div><!--indexTopMenuOut/-->
</div><!--indexTopRow2/-->

</div><!--indexTopInn/-->
</div><!--indexTopOut/-->




</div><!--indexRootInn/-->
</div><!--indexRootOut/-->

</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/apd4q5kc/2/

Comment: Сделайте width auto для кнопки, и она будет длинной в текст. Ну а чтобы смотрелось нормально на 800px используйте @media на css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#indexTopFindOut {

    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
    min-width: auto;

    padding-right: 30px;

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3c17ua9t/